# Как интегрировать vue 3 с этапом сборке на проекте с bitrix

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, битрикс, vite

Немного контекста. Сайт написан на bitrix, преимущественно на JQ.
Я постепенно переписываю его на нативный js и vue
Vue подключен через script и код пишется без этапа сборки.
Разработка ведется через ssh на клонах сайта и потом все заливается на прод через git
На vue пишу каждый функционал отдельным приложением (К примеру писал конфигуратор для мебели и это новый createApp, поиск с выпадающими предложениями, историей и тд, это новый createApp и так далее)
Понимаю какой это костыль, но ничего лучше пока не придумал с этим битриксом.

Давно хочу интегрировать этап сборки, что бы разработка была комфортной но не понимаю с какой стороны подойди.
Сразу перейти на vue и отказаться от jq невозможно.
Возможно кто то подскажет какую структуру стоит создать и где размещать, как это все потом собирать и так далее.
Документации на что то подобное пока не нашел, не у vue, не у vite, не у webpack.
Буду рад любой информации или возможно вектору, где ее можно найти

Comment: Здесь смотрел? https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=176&INDEX=Y

Comment: Возможно, будет полезно https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=12435&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.4776.3635.12435